# Do we need to deal with [brexit]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tagging

Some questions tagged [brexit](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/brexit) are about claims that are being made by pro or anti Brexit figures, sometimes making a claim about the status quo of Britain's involvement in the EU, but do not appear to be directly about the process of Britain leaving the EU.

For example, [Is 90% of world trade conducted on WTO terms?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/39899/is-90-of-world-trade-conducted-on-wto-terms) and [Is the UK's trade with the EU artifically inflated by having to ship its exports via Europe?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/35375/is-the-uks-trade-with-the-eu-artifically-inflated-by-having-to-ship-its-exports) and [Does the UK provide 50% of EU's waters? And does this imply anything about fishing rights?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/43912/does-the-uk-provide-50-of-eus-waters-and-does-this-imply-anything-about-fishi)

Is this an appropriate use of the tag?

Comment: Sounds kind of like the trump tag being used for claims made by trump, rather than claims about trump.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, questions about the status quo of Britain's involvement in the EU should not be tagged as [brexit].

It's understandable that these questions come up in discussions about brexit, and their answers can help to form an opinion about brexit, but the questions themselves are independent of brexit. Unless the cause of the claims are attributed to brexit (such as [Was there a spike in hate crimes after the Brexit referendum?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/35861/was-there-a-spike-in-hate-crimes-after-the-brexit-referendum)), they should not be tagged [brexit].

If Britain does complete its departure from the EU, we'll likely see a lot more suitable use of the [brexit] tag, but right now, most questions are extrapolating existing claims into predictions about the future, and those existing claims stand on their own.

Comment: I've untagged the three questions I referred to in my meta question.